# Is it good idea to generate features from data points similarity comparison?

Tags: feature-selection, data-transformation, kernel-trick, feature-engineering, rbf-kernel

I know about polynomial features in machine learning, which can introduce nonlinearity to original dataset. I also heard about binning, which also allows us to create new features from existing ones.

However now, I am thinking whether it is possible to generate new features by comparing data points similarity.

My idea is having a feature which tells something like "what is cosine distance of current datapoint's feature vector and feature vector of datapoint n". This way I could compare all data points and have many new features (for each datapoint I would have features comparing it to all datapoints - number of new features would be equal to number of datapoints).

When I would do a prediction for new datapoint, I would have to compare it with all training datapoints to generate these additional features.

My questions are:
1) is this idea good or bad?
2) is this idea somehow related to kernels? I was not able to understand them, but from what I read, it seems for me that they operate with this idea.
3) is this idea or something similar already implemented somewhere, if it's not completely stupid (in other words: am I not trying to invent wheel?)

Thanks